# Windows jutter from place to place in classic desktop with ATI driver

Tags: 11.04, ati, gnome

I just uninstalled Gnome 3 and had to reactivate my ATI driver, it should now be working fine but it isn't.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with the classic theme and when I drag the windows around they jutter from place to place, this never used to happen.

How can I fix the lag?

Cheers,

Comment: The Visual Effects tab in Appearance Settings has disappeared, I might add.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it's related to the "Sync to VBlank"

**First** - make sure you have CCSM installed. If not, then from a terminal type

```
 sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

**Second** - After it's done installing, click on the Unity launcher button in the top left and type **ccsm** and then hit enter


**Third** - With CCSM open, in the General area, click on OpenGL and UNCHECK the **"Sync to VBlank"**
[image]

**Fourth** - Click on Back at the bottom to go back to the main ccsm menu, then click on Composite and UNCHECK **Detect Refresh Rate** and drag the Refresh Rate slider all the way to 200
[image]

Comment: I've done all of the above and nothing has changed; I relogged and nothing happened.

Comment: Hmm...try checking in the ATI Catalyst Control Center. Open that up, go to 3D, then "More Settings". Under "Wait for Vertical refresh", drag the slider all the way to the left.

Comment: That didn't work either :/

Comment: I think I'll just do a reinstall. Thanks for all the help though!